# What will the probability of scoring prime no. of goals in a game?

Tags: probability

I am absolutely at a loss to understand how to proceed. Can you please help me?

Sudz is fascinated by prime numbers and he wonders what the probability is that at least one of them, Raghav or himself will be able to score n number of goals, where n is a prime number. Every game lasts 90 minutes, and Sudz observes that every 5 minutes, there is a decent chance that a goal may be scored by him or Raghav, so he splits the match into 'sections' of 5 minutes. The first section of the match lasts from minutes 0-5 (0th minute to end of 4th minute) , the second section lasts from minutes 5-10 (start of 5th minute to start of end of 9th minute). During each section of the game, there is a 'x' percent chance that Raghav will score a goal, and a 'y' percent chance that Sudz will score a goal. Sudz knows that Raghav is a good player and also has faith in his own abilities as a good FIFA player. So he fairly assumes that during every section of the game, one of them scores at most 1 goal, not more.
Given x and y, your job is to predetermine the probability that atleast one of them, Sudz or Raghav end up with n number of goals, where n can be any prime number.

Example

## Input:

x=78
y=12

## Output:

0.6677

Comment: The 2 events are independent.

Comment: Okay.  Since there are 90 minutes, the maximum score either player can achieve is...

Comment: You mean 18, I suspect.

Comment: yes, slip of tongue (rather, keyboard).

Comment: Since S and R score independently, you can work out the chance that S gets a prime score, then the chance that R gets a prime score, and combine them accordingly, $Pr(S \cup R) = 1 - Pr(S^c \cap R^c)$.

Comment: ok, thanks. on it.

Comment: I think that it'll be something like 1 / 18 c 2 + 1 / 18 c 3 + 1 / 18 c 5 + ... + 1/ 18 c 17. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Looking at the binomial distribution is on the right track.  Needs a bit of polishing.

Comment: Couldn't go any further. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the players Raghav and Sudz are assumed to have independent chances $x$ and $y$ of scoring in each five minute period (of which there are $18$), we can compute $Pr(S)$ and $Pr(R)$ where $S,R$ are respectively the events that Sudz or Raghav get a prime number score over the entire course of play.

This is sufficient because by independence $Pr(S \text{ or } R) = Pr(S) + Pr(R) - Pr(S)Pr(R)$.

We show how to make the computation of $Pr(R)$ since the case for $Pr(S)$ amounts merely to replacing the scoring probability $x$ by $y$.

The binomial expansion:

$$ 1 = \sum_{k=0}^{18} \binom{18}{k} x^k (1-x)^{18-k} $$

gives the probabilities that Sudz will score $k$ points, ranging from $k = 0$ to $k=18$, term by term.

We are only interested in the outcomes where $k$ is prime:

$$ k = 2,3,5,7,11,13,17 $$

Thus $Pr(R) = \binom{18}{2} x^2 (1-x)^{16} + \binom{18}{3} x^3 (1-x)^{15} + \ldots + \binom{18}{13} x^{13} (1-x)^5 + \binom{18}{17} x^{17} (1-x) $.

**Added:** Using this formula I was able to confirm the result given in the Question, that when $x=0.78$ and $y=0.12$, the chance at least one score will be prime is approximately $0.6677$.  I found it convenient to create a spreadsheet with one column of the primes $k$, and two columns for the binomial distribution of cases $x,y$.  Adding the columns gives respectively $Pr(S)$ and $Pr(R)$, from which the final result $Pr(S) + Pr(R) - Pr(S)Pr(R) = 1 - (1-Pr(S))(1-Pr(R))$.